# Three.JS How to animate an imported 3D object in scene?

Tags: three.js

Been doing this for 10 hours or so and still can't figure out how should I be able (or indeed should I be able at all) to move imported object in scene.

Here are my code samples:

```
// OBJECT (.obj loader)
var onProgress = function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
    }
};
var onError = function (xhr) { };

THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath('./');
mtlLoader.load('object.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath('./');
    objLoader.load('object.obj', function (object) {
        object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 20;
        object.position.set(1100, 0, -600);
        object.castShadow = true;
        object.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(object);
    }, onProgress, onError);
});
```

Now the object is in the scene. I can look at it, no problem, but when I try:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    object.rotation.x += 0.005;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
}
```

Nothing. Just nothing. If I have a crate created in `init()`, I can rotate it in `animate()` with `crate.rotation.x += 0.005;` with no problems whatsoever, but the imported object... no. Nothing happens. It says:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'rotation' of undefined or null reference

Can you help? How to animate imported .obj file in three.js?

Comment: Have you checked the JS console for errors? It looks like you haven't created a variable to keep track of `object` , so it won't be defined outside of the loading callback.

Comment: Yeah sure. It says:
 "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'rotation' of undefined or null reference"
But I just don't know what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
var model;
var onProgress = function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
    } 
}; 
var onError = function (xhr) { }; 
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); 
mtlLoader.setPath('./'); 
mtlLoader.load('object.mtl', function (materials) { 
    materials.preload(); 
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(); 
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials); 
    objLoader.setPath('./'); 
    objLoader.load('object.obj', function (object) { 
            object.scale.x = object.scale.y = 
        object.scale.z = 20; 
            object.position.set(1100, 0, -600);
            object.castShadow = true; 
            object.receiveShadow = true;
            model = object;
            scene.add(model); 
    }, onProgress, onError); });
```

And then change the animate function,

```
function animate() { 
    requestAnimationFrame( animate ); 
    model.rotation.x += 0.005; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
    controls.update(); 
}
```

You were referring to `object` which is out of scope in the `animate` function. I changed it by using variable `model`.